# iterate over jquery.data() and find plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

My JQuery plugin registers on the element data attribute `plugin_myplugin`. When I pull all data attributes I get an object like this:

```
element.data();

Object:
 id: 123
 somedata: foo
 someotherdata: baz
 plugin_myplugin: Plugin (Object)
```

Now I need to iterate over this and find my plugin by testing the keys for `_plugin`

iterating with `$.each` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)` shows me only

```
id
somedata
someotherdata
```

I have found no way to iterate over the returned object so that `plugin_myplugin` key can be tested

Edit: Reason for testing `plugin_` is: I need to find out which plugin is registered. I can be plugin_myplugin or plugin_myotherplugin

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to do this? I'm sure there's a better way to achieve whatever you need to do

Comment: why doesnt `var d = element.data(); var plugin = d['plugin_myplugin']` work? why do you have to iterate?

Comment: Iteration is what all the cool kids do nowadays.

Comment: @Delcon : can you provide some jsFilddle to see the error.

Comment: I edited my question to give you the reason for iterating over all data()